# AWS SSO password expiration

Tags: amazon-web-services, passwords, single-sign-on

The Password expiration can be set for IAM users in an aws account. But how can I set password expiration for SSO users in an aws organization. I don't see any options for it. Is there any a way for expiration in aws or through other ways?